# How to use a socket as the pty in libvte?

Tags: gtk3, pygtk, pty, vte

The goal is to create a remote terminal emulator that runs on machine A which controls machine B by sending and receiving data using TCP socket connection mapped to a forked pty on machine B

machine A is running the GUI terminal emulator

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("Vte", "2.91")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Vte, Gdk


class Shell(Vte.Terminal):
    def __init__(self, socket=None):
        super().__init__()
```

machine B is the client that creates a pty and maps its stdin,stdout,stderr to the socket
a simple implementation of the code running on machine B can be found in this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/QAX-A-Team/ptyshell/master/pty.c)

the problem is that `libvte` does not provide a direct way to specify the socket that offer such functionality.

there is the function `spawn_with_fds_async` but I am not sure how to use this function with the socket